# before destroy call back

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, destroy

I am a novice Ruby programmer working on a Rails API.  I have a Location model and a User model, and a location has many users.  They are related like this:

```
class Location << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: :users
end

class User << ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
end
```

I want to put a constraint on the Location model so that a Location model object won't be destroyed if it has one or more associated Users.

Consider the case of Mumbai, which is a Location and it has one or more Users.  As such, I cannot destroy that Location; I can destroy only if there are no users for a particular location.

How do to handle destroying records in a protected manner, such as this?

Comment: you can put a check in your destroy action if location.users.present? then restrict from delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your Location model to look like this:

```
class Location << ActiveRecord::Base
  before_destroy :confirm_safe_to_destroy

  has_many: :users

private

  def confirm_safe_to_destroy
    return false if users.any?
  end
end
```

This will use the `before_destroy` handler to check if it's safe to destroy the Location model object.  The `confirm_safe_to_destroy` method returns false to halt the destroy process if there are any users associated with the location.

Answer (score 1):

Just add something like this to your model:

```
# in app/models/location.rb
before_destroy :ensure_no_users

private
def ensure_no_users
  return false if users.any?
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Location Model add the following:

```
 before_destroy :check_for_users #This will be run before destroy is called.



def check_for_users
  return false if self.users.present?
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also add an error message to the instance:

```
class Location << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: :users
  before_destroy :check_for_users

  def check_for_users
    return if users.any?
    errors[:base] << "some error message"
    false
  end
end
```

Then you can even access the error message in your controller:

```
if @location.destroy?
  # success flow - location was deleted
else
  @location.errors.full_messages #=> "some error message"
end
```